# $M$ and $N$ are matrices that satisfy $MNMN=0$,what can we say about $NMNM$.

Tags: linear-algebra

From my personal point of view, we cannot deduce that $NMNM=0$,but I can't find a counterexample.

Comment: @chinamath nice link, is that site good in general? Might sign up?

Comment: I've been able to deduce the following: let $M$ be a $a \times b$ matrix and $N$ be a $b \times c$ matrix (for multiplication to be defined). Then $MNMN$ is defined if and only if $a = c$. So thus, $MNMN$ is a square matrix. But since $a = c$, $MN$ is square as well, and $(MN)^{2} = O$, the zero matrix. Thus $MN$ is said to be nilpotent. There is a theorem that says that 0 is the only eigenvalue of $MN$. But I'm not sure where you could go from here.

Comment: @Clarinetist the link as the first comment gives a nice construction. Even if you cant read chinese, i am sure you can scroll down to read the solution. There is a very nice 'guess and verify' approach.

Answer (score 4):

I am not able to read Chinese, I hope I do not repeat anything.

This is a problem posed on $51$st Putnam competition.

It was posted 
the first day as a fifth problem.

I post the counterexample in matrices
$$
B=
\left (
\begin{array}{ccc}
0&0&1\\
1&0&0\\
0&0&0
\end{array}
\right )
A=
\left (
\begin{array}{ccc}
0&0&1\\
0&0&0\\
0&1&0
\end{array}
\right )
$$
I believe the easiest way to construct a counterexample by fixing a base 
$e_1,e_2,e_3$ and then having $B,A$ have a kernel and an image some permutation of these vectors. And after playing around you will construct a counterexample.

Here is a link with a very illuminating solution from a database with [solutions](http://www.math.niu.edu/~rusin/problems-math/putnam.90) of Putnam problems.

[All years](http://www.math.niu.edu/~rusin/problems-math/)

Comment: Lol pretty similar to one of the solution on the link.